# Button in ribbonbar for Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I try to develop a Outlook Add-Ins (pure js/html app), not an VSTO / COM app with c#.

I found a way to add a button to the ribbonbar, but it seems to be only for Outlook 2016: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt267546.aspx

But, is there a way to add a button in the ribbonbar for Outlook 2013?

Can't find anything even on dev.outlook.com...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop a COM add-in then (VSTO). See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) for more information.

There are two main ways for creating a custom UI in VSTO add-ins:

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)

Moreover, your ribbon commands can be displayed for Exchange profiles only (where Office Apps can be run). But COM add-ins are run for all kind of profiles in Outlook.